# How to create nested record of another model from controller's create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The Controller is Pms::Grn and I want to create a record for Pms::Srn 
    if one of Grn's params present how can I achieve it following is code

**Controller**

```
class Pms::GrnsController < Pms::PmsModulesController

 def create
   @pms_grn = Pms::Grn.new(pms_grn_params)
   respond_to do |format|
     if @pms_grn.save
       if params[:pms_grn][:rejected_qty].present?
         @pms_srn = Pms::Srn.create()# here I want to create record for  
                                     # pms_srn with it's nested model
       end
     end
   end

 end
```

**Model**

```
class Pms::Srn < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :pms_srn_inventories
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pms_srn_inventories
end
```

Comment: Try `@pms_grn. pms_srn_inventories.new()` (or `create()`) to create an instance of the associate model

Comment: Does `pms_grn_params` contain the nested attributes for inventory `pms_srn_inventories_attributes`? If it does, did you try permitting these params?

Comment: Thanks for help..! yes pms_grn_params contain the nested attributes for inventory I permitted it. but while creating pms_srn_inventories I have to save parent first. so I use after_create callback but it is not working..